# Return a range in Column 2 based on the look-up results in Column 1

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to achieve this task in Excel. In column 1, I look up each letter, and return the values (yes or no) in column 2. If there is one value is yes, then it is yes for that that letter, otherwise it is no.

The second part is fairly easy. Once I have the range of cells for each letter, then I can use COUNTIF and IF. However, how to do return a range of cells in column 2 based on column 1? Match or lookup functions stop when they find the first match, but I need the function to go through all the values in Column 1 and return all the matches in Column 2.

A     Yes

A     No

B     Yes

B     Yes

B     No

C     No

C     No

This can also be multiple values for example

A   Yes

A   No

A   Unknown

A

I expect to get a table that is

A   Yes

B   Yes

C   No

Comment: `FILTER` perhaps if your version of Excel supports it.

Comment: Hi @BigBen, thank you for the respone. I tried filter. I could use `counta` to summarize all values, however I can't use `countif`. The condition is that if there  is one record shows "yes", then it is yes, otherwise it is no. I can't use the this logic test when using filter function.

Comment: It's a bit hard to follow your explanation. Can you specify 1) sample data, and 2) expected result?

Comment: Hello @BigBen, I edited my post. So basically I would like to have a table that is like: A yes  B yes C No

Comment: Can Column 2 only be Yes or No?

Comment: Yes, they are either yes or no, although I have another column that have multiple values and I need to do the similar thing to that column as well. But I figured I can add an extra column to convert to "yes" or "no"

Comment: If you know how to handle multiple text values, would really appreciate!

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the logic is for multiple text values. Is it that their corresponding values in column 2 are all the same? As always, sample data and the expected result would be helpful.

Comment: Hi @BigBen, I just edited my post. The values can be A yes A no A unknown or A null.  But the answer you posted would work. If you can post it back, I will select it as the correct answer. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, something like:

```
=UNIQUE(A1:A7)
```

to return the unique values from column 1,
and

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A1:A7,D1#,B1:B7,"Yes")>0,"Yes","No")
```

to return Yes or No.

[image]